# How to fix Google Apps Script for local time and automatically clear a cell

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am creating a shared agenda that has to be filled by different people. Everytime they modify a certain cell, the date of change (day) is reported in another cell on the same row. The code below is currently working, but there are 3 minor problems:

1. The local time is not correct (I am living in italy)
2. I would like to see the time as well (hours:minutes)
3. If the modified cell is cleared (like if the text is deleted), also the date of change should disappear.

I find this type of code difficult to debug and would appreciate any help. 
Thank you in advance,

```
function onEdit(event) {
var cell = event.source.getActiveCell();   
var sheet = cell.getSheet();
var headers= sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0]; 
var statusCol = headers.indexOf('Status') + 1 ; 

var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if (event.range.columnStart != 2) {

} else {
    ss.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 5)
        .setValue(getDate(new Date()));
}

var tt = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if (event.range.columnStart != 34) {
    return;
} else {
    tt.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 37)
        .setValue(getDate(new Date()));
}
}

function getDate(d) {
if (d) {
    return d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getYear();
}
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a `return;` here `if (event.range.columnStart != 2) {
  //here
} else {
    ss.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 5)
        .setValue(getDate(new Date()));
}`

Comment: The question is too broad as each point could have it's own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Add TimeZone, Hours, Minutes and deletes Datetime if cell contents is deleted.

It adds hours and minutes in 24 hour format with a timezone correction and if e.value is null then it deletes the contents of the datetime cell.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;   
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(rg.columnStart!=2 && rg.columnStart!=34){return;}
  if(rg.columnStart==2){
    if(e.value) {
      sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, 5).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,new Date().getDate(),new Date().getHours(),new Date().getMinutes()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"d/MMM/yyyy HH:mm"));
    }else{
      sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, 5).setValue('');
    }
  }
  if (rg.columnStart==34) {
    if(e.value) {
      sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, 37).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,new Date().getDate(),new Date().getHours(),new Date().getMinutes()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"d/MMM/yyyy HH:mm"));
    }else{
      sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, 37).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

- [Spreadsheet Edit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Unfortunately, the time is 6 hours earlier than my actual timezone. In addition, once delete the content of the cell, the cell containing the date is not deleted as well. I don't know if it makes the difference, but column 3 and 34 are drop-down lists

Comment: Yes it would’ve been nice to know that they were drop downs as I don’t have any drop downs on my sheets. This worked on my end so you may have to do a little debugging since you didn’t include all the details and your question

Comment: The spreadsheet has a time zone and the script has a time zone so you may have to adjust them.

Comment: I am sorry about the missing details. I am not really aware about codes. Could you please help me with how to fix the code to take into account the drop down menu? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Update your question with new information and code and create a public version of the spreadsheet so we can verify operation.  Take look at [mcve] and [ask].  Or if you wish you can check this one closed and start another.  Your call.